# Insert React-component into input-element

Tags: reactjs

There are some input-elements in my React-app, mostly - . I need to implement a special character function, just like in messengers: I type "@" - then the list of available users appears. When I continue typing the name - users are being filtered accordingly. For diferrent input-elements - a different result that a user can choose from (sometimes completely unrelated to that element).

Telegram for example,

[image: Telegram example]

My main idea - put a handler on onKey-event. When "@" symbol is pressed - insert existing React-component with the list of users.

I tried . Does not allow inserting a component, only text.
I tried . The component is inserted, but I can't continue writing to search for users.

How can this functionality be implemented? (Perhaps I have the wrong approach initially)

Comment: There are libraries which help you do that. Check this one out. https://www.npmjs.com/package/tweet-textarea-react You can explore how the feature is implemented from their github link.